# Export HTML5 form data to CSV?

Tags: javascript, html

Any ideas on Exporting HTML5 Form data to CSV please?

I can only use HTML5 or Javascript or both.

Thanks

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Any sort of "export" purely from within the browser client is going to be problematic. What sorts of constraints are there (i.e., is this an intranet project for a population chained to Internet Explorer)?

Comment: Basically what I've got is a HTML5 form where I have input types, selects, where I just fill up the form. Needs to be offline so it's not like I can use php etc...Supposed you have fields to fill in: Name, Surname, Address and Country (from a select box) .. then out of that data I want to create or save it into a CSV file. How would I go around that please? Hope this extra info helps.

Comment: I've been thinking. What about if I used HTML5 LocalStorage and created a Databas, Tables and then saved the data... would it then be easier to export the records to csv format? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what I'm going to have to do: 1. If there IS internet connection ... then save the data to MySQL Table. 2. Using PHP run a script on the MySQL DB to export the data to CSV.

I'll use something like this for example:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'mysqlUser';
$pass = 'myUserPass';
$db = 'myDatabase';
$table = 'products_info';
$file = 'export';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field']."; ";
$i++;
}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $rowr[$j]."; ";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Stack is not the place for your inner monologues.

Answer (score 0):

You could just display the form data in CSV format in the browser (maybe in a popup) and have the user do a File -> Save Page (assuming it doesn't have to be fully automated).

Comment: What I'm looking for is more like having a button that will let the user save as csv.

Comment: You could base64 encode the csv data and give them a link to "download" it.  I'm not sure exactly what the code would look like, but I'm sure it's possibly in pure JS without any server-side code involved.

Comment: It looks like Javascript is not that powerful after all. I might have to save the data to an online db and then using php do the conversion.

Comment: OK, this is what I'm going to have to do: 1. If the IS internet connection ... then save the data to MySQL Table. 2. Using PHP run a script on the MySQL DB to export the data to CSV.